# Google App Engine- Setting HTTP header to test X-AppEngine

Tags: http, google-app-engine, http-headers, webapp2

I am using X-AppEngine to find the location of users. I don' think there is a way to change the header information to alter the location. But I would like to test X-AppEngine-City for different cities. Is there a way of testing this?

Below is my code.

```
city = self.request.headers.get('X-AppEngine-City')
coords = self.request.headers.get('X-AppEngine-CityLatLong')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "test X-AppEngine-City for different cities"? Provide an example what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @MihailRussu for example, if a user is accessing my site from London, the city variable will be assigned to London. However, since I am testing my own application, I can't find a way to test the function outside of my current location.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. You can change the `city` variable to whatever you want, yourself. You may also be interested in [detecting whether you're running in production or dev server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-local-server#detecting_application_runtime_environment) and act based on that. You may also try something like `city = self.request.get('city') or self.request.headers.get('X-AppEngine-City')` while testing and then adding `?city=London` to your requests sounds like will result in what you're asking.

Comment: @MihailRussu I think your solution would be the best way - hard coding the city variable - for testing purposes.  I learned that X-AppEngine determines the location based on your IP address but I cannot change the header information to alter the IP address. Thank you for your advice.